# Why namaskara with open hands in panchakaccha?

Tags: rituals, practice, sandhyavandanam

Why open hands in panchakaccha and crossed hands in datti while doing gothrabhivadana? Datti is just rounding of dhoti without panchakaccha.

Comment: Translate  the words into English. What is datti?